# What is wrong with this python script?

Tags: python, python3

I have this code:

```
from sys import argv
import os
bold = "\033[1m"
reset = "\033[0;0m"

try:
    argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print("\nNo arguments! Add \"-h\" or \"--help\" for more info." + bold + "\n\nNow look what you've done!" + reset)
else:
    pass

if argv[1] == "-h" or "--help":
    print("\nxxxx, version 0.0.2")
    print("xxxx is a simple tool for the command line used for quickly saving\n\
chunks of text, while providing more functionality than the traditional method\n\
(e.g. echo \"HELLO WORLD\" > hi.txt) used in bash.")
    print("\nUsage: sans-sheriff [text] [directory] [options]")
    print("\nOptions:\n\
    -h, --help                Display this help message and exit.\n\
    -v, --verbose             Output more verbosity.\n\
    -e=utf8, --encoding       Sets the encoding. Default is utf-8.\n\
       utf16\n\
       utf32\n\
       ascii\n\
  iso (8859-1)\n\
-text                     Sets the filetype. Default is \".txt\".\n\
 html\n\
 rtf\n\
 tex\n\
-o, --open                Open the file directly after.\n\
\n\
e.g. xxxx \"Hello World\" /home/user/Documents/myfile -e=utf32")
else:
    try:
        argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        print("No directory argument! Add \"-h\" or \"--help\" fopr mor info." + bold + "\n\nNow look what you've done!" + reset)
    else:
        pass
    usrtxt = argv[1]
    usrdir = argv[2]
    usrtxt = open(usrdir, "w")
```

It is supposed to create text files based on a users' arguments, like this:

```
xxxx \"Hello World\" /home/user/Documents/myfile
```

But whenever it is launched like the example provided, it just loads the output that would have been produced when `-h` or `--help` is argued...
It doesn't seem logical why it would do this, and I'm quite a newbie to python as well, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `or` incorrectly. The proper way to do this in your example would be:

```
if argv[1] == "-h" or argv[1] == "--help":
```

Or is a Boolean operator that describes what to do with two different comparisons. So what you have provided would be like saying

```
keep_going = False
if argv[1] == "-h":
    keep_going = True

if "--help":
    keep_going = True
```

Which doesn't make sense. Technically just having `or "--help"` is `True` because `"--help"` is a non-empty String.

In addition, thanks to [Timo](https://askubuntu.com/users/20837/timo), you could use

```
if argv[1] in ("-h", "--help"):
```

Which is considered more the *Python way*

Lastly, you should be looking in to things like [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for Python to properly handle arguments as they may not always be in the same order.

In the future, questions strictly regarding code are better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) which is likely better suited for programming questions.

Comment: Also, you can avoid the newlines and constant escaping by using triple-quoted strings. `'''...'''`

Comment: Thanks George and Marco (my name is also marco ;)) everything is fixed now. Just some shenanigans with the open() function...

Comment: best answer in 40 secs...

Comment: wow, your website is really nice btw

Comment: If you have to compare a variable against multiple values, I always use the `in` operator. It makes it more clean, shorter, and easy to extend. Example: `if argv[1] in ("-h", "--help"):`